# For a .NET Web Application, is it possible to have Apache HTTPD as web server and IIS as Application server?

Tags: .net, apache, iis, webserver, appserver

Me and a colleague were discussing if it is possible to have a simple 3 tier web application running in the following configuration / setup.

It is a simple question, however I do not have a machine with the necessary applications and rights to test it out. Hence posting here for your help.

**Web Server:** Apache HTTPD running on RHEL

**App Server:** IIS running on Windows

**DB:** MS SQL

Emphasis is more on the Apache HTTPD and IIS linkage / usage.

Can IIS be used purely as an Application server, leaving the web server duties to Apache HTTPD?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Sure it can. Why do you think it couldn’t? But you haven’t explained this “linkage”

Comment: Or we should say if you use Apache as a reverse proxy, any web server/application server can be put behind it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: The question was more about how or can it be done. We have not implemented such a setup, hence. Linkage means, are there any incompatibility issues between HTTPD and IIS, which otherwise might have worked perfectly well, let's say in a exclusive HTTPD-JBoss combo or IIS configurations.

Comment: @LexLi: To put it across the way you have, I agree logically it is possible. But if we go and do it as an actual implementation, will there be any issues? Apologies, as my experience in such a setup is scarce, bordering on none.

Comment: @aeon then start experimenting to gain the necessary experience instead of shooting the breeze.

Comment: @LexLi: Sure, thanks for your help and advice!